# Login screen black (and non-functional) after 18.04 update

Tags: nvidia, kubuntu

I updated my Kubuntu system to 18.04 today. The update had been delayed as 'uncalculatable' for a few days. I removed one PPA for MakeMKV and the update proceeded without complaints. After the reboot the system was running nouveux (sp) but all threee monitors functioned as before so I used:

ubuntu-drivers devices
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall

to get nvidia-drivers-390.48-0ubuntu3 installed.

Upon reboot SDDM doesn't function and I'm unable to log in. After looking at dmesg it said (paraphrasing) that nvidia-driver needed a dedicated VGA console driver and a post I found somewhere led me to editing the following line in /etc/default/grub

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="video=vesafb:off vga=normal"
#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

and then updating grub. This allowed the system to boot to a command line. SDDM no longer appears to start at all. From there I can log in, run startx, X11 comes up and everything works OK from there.

So, I'm really unsure at this point how to get sddm working again and would appreciate any pointers.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This was solved using:

```
sudo apt-get install sddm
sudo dpkg-reconfigure sddm
```

Comment: In my case this post _was_ the complete answer to my question.

Comment: This fixed my problem, thanks! I also ran "systemctl restart sddm" afterwards to start the login display.
SYMPTOM: Blank screen after upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04LTS to Ubuntu 18.04LTS. Video card is NVidia Quadro K620. driver was nvidia-drivers-390 [nvidia-driver-390_390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb]

Answer (score 0):

Having an issue with 390 too. Can't make it to work with 18.04 4.17.17 GDM3. Stucks on "[OK] Started GNOME Display manager" and nothing helps. DMESG have nothing on that.